# How to iterate on results inside then() and call other chained then() inside the loop

Tags: typescript, promise

I cannot find any documentation or example in typescript  that illustrates how to nest then() inside a loop which is inside a then().

I have the following chained then() functions that work perfectly.

but i need to make the functions 1 to 3 run n number of times based on an array property of the process object after it has been returned from the _promptUploadDialog

```
    .then(process => this._promptUploadDialog(process))            
        .then(process => this._function1(process))
        .then(process => this._function2(process))
        .then(process => this._function3(process))
```

needs to become something like this:

```
 .then(process => this._promptUploadDialog(process)
     process.array1.forEach(function (value) {
        process.currentobject = value;
        this._function1(process))
            .then(process => this._function2(process))
            .then(process => this._function3(process))
     }); 
)
```

Tried

```
return Promise.resolve<UploadDataProcess>({
            uploadResponse: undefined,           
            arrayProp: [1,2,3]
        })
            .then(process => this._promptUploadDialog(process))
            .then(process => 
                process.arrayProp.forEach((value) => {
                    this._function1(process)
                        .then(process => this._function2(process))
                        .then(process => this._function3(process));
                    })
            );
```

But I am getting a compile error:

> TS2322    Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.

Answer (score 0):

What if you do something like:

```
.then(process => this._promptUploadDialog(process))
  .then(process => process.array1.forEach((value)=>
     {
       this._function1(process)
        .then(process => this._function2(process))
        .then(process => this._function3(process))
     });
```

your functions 1,2,3 are going to be in a loop based on process.array1 that what you want if I understand your question.

Comment: I am getting  a compile error :  TS2322 Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<UploadDataProcess>'

Comment: What if you return at the end of each process? like:

.then((process) => {return this._promptUploadDialog(process)})
  .then((process) =>{process.array1.forEach((value)=>
     {
       this._function1(process)
        .then((process) => { return this._function2(process)})
        .then((process) => { return this._function3(process)})
     }});

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `{ ... }` syntax for a lambda function definition, it does not `return` the last instruction (as opposed to the `(arg) => statement` which returns the value of `statement`).

So, here you see you have a problem with `void` being returned by the last `Promise` instead of your data type `UploadDataProcess`. That's because you miss the `return` keyword. Just add it and it will be ok:

```
return Promise.resolve<UploadDataProcess>({
        uploadResponse: undefined,           
        arrayProp: [1,2,3]
    })
        .then(process => this._promptUploadDialog(process))
        .then(process => 
            process.arrayProp.forEach((value) => {
                return /* <-- HERE */ this._function1(process)
                    .then(process => this._function2(process))
                    .then(process => { this._function3(process));
                                       return process; /* <-- and return process at the end if it's your object */ }
                })
        );
```

Comment: Added return but still getting the same exact error

Comment: Then, what does your `function3` return? I don't know your code, you just need to return the `UploadDataProcess` at the end of the lambda function. What is that object?

Comment: I updated the code in case it's the `process` object.